# Maintain aspect ratio while rotating the video through MPV media player

Tags: kubuntu, 21.04, mpv-media-player

I am currently using the `mpv` media player in Kubuntu 21.04. To rotate the video by keyboard, I edited the `~/.config/mpv/input.conf` file and added:

```
r cycle_values video-rotate 90 180 270 0
```

Now, whenever I play a video with `mpv` and press <kbd>r</kbd>, the  video will be rotated by 90 degrees, as shown in the image below:

[image: rotated video]

However, this also changes the aspect ratio after rotating by some degrees.
You can see the default image of this video without any rotation at this time below:

[image: non-rotated video]

There was no issue when I was using `mpv` before in elementary OS.
This issue came up when I started using Kubuntu.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and add the contents of your `~/.config/mpv/mpv.conf` and `~/.config/mpv/input.conf` files?

Comment: I just checked that I don't have `mpv.conf` inside `~/.config/mpv/`. I only have `input.conf` and the content of input.conf is `r cycle_values video-rotate 90 180 270 0`

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem on Ubuntu 20.04 with GNOME. However, you may take a look at the `geometry`  and `autofit-larger` options of mpv, that could perhaps help. For exampe, I have added in my `mpv.conf` the following (in separate lines): `geometry=50%:50%` and `autofit-larger=50%x50%`.

Comment: Okay, no worry. But thanks to help me again.